# Spawning threads in newly spawned processes and using print to view thread state in Python

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a python script that creates 2 new processes. Then, within each new process, I create 3 threads.

```
import os
import threading
import multiprocessing as mp
import time


def extra_threads():
    x = 7
    while x != 0:
        x -= 1
        for specific_thread in threading.enumerate():
            print('THREAD:', specific_thread, f'X Value: {x},', os.getpid())


def new_process():
    print('PROCESS: New Process PID:', os.getpid())
    print('PROCESS: Thread Count:',
          threading.active_count())
    for specific_thread in threading.enumerate(): 
        print('PROCESS:', specific_thread)
    print('PROCESS: CREATING 3 ADDITIONAL THREADS IN PID:', os.getpid())

    for y in range(3):
        t = threading.Thread(target=extra_threads)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

    print('PROCESS: Thread Count: ', threading.active_count(), 'PID:', os.getpid())

    while True:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # display information about this process
    print('Parent Process ID: ', os.getpid())  # Get's the unique Process ID of this process
    print('Parent Thread Count: ', threading.active_count())  # Shows that it is initially 1 thread to his process

    for thread in threading.enumerate():
        print('MAIN PROGRAM THREADS:', thread)  # Prints information about each of those threads

    print('\nSTARTING 2 NEW PROCESSES...')
    print()
    for z in range(2):
        print(f'Starting {z + 1} New Process...')
        print()
        mp.Process(target=new_process).start()
        time.sleep(1)
        print()
```

When I look at the processes at the terminal, the output is as expected.
I have 2 processes (ps -eF) and 3 threads for each process (when I run ps -L ).

However, the print statements (in the extra_thread() function) appear twice at the terminal for each thread in each process. This is observerd by the printed X value repeating multiple times.

Can someone explain why that is happening?

```
THREAD: <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140020333217600)> X Value: 6, 449
**THREAD: <Thread(Thread-1, started daemon 140020326205184)> X Value: 6, 449**
THREAD: <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140020333217600)> X Value: 6, 449
THREAD: <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140020333217600)> X Value: 5, 449
THREAD: <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140020333217600)> X Value: 6, 449
**THREAD: <Thread(Thread-1, started daemon 140020326205184)> X Value: 6, 449
THREAD: <Thread(Thread-1, started daemon 140020326205184)> X Value: 6, 449**
THREAD: <Thread(Thread-2, started daemon 140020317751040)> X Value: 6, 449
THREAD: <Thread(Thread-1, started daemon 140020326205184)> X Value: 5, 449
THREAD: <Thread(Thread-3, started daemon 140020309296896)> X Value: 6, 449
THREAD: <Thread(Thread-2, started daemon 140020317751040)> X Value: 5, 449
THREAD: <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140020333217600)> X Value: 5, 449
THREAD: <Thread(Thread-1, started daemon 140020326205184)> X Value: 5, 449
THREAD: <Thread(Thread-3, started daemon 140020309296896)> X Value: 5, 449
THREAD: <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140020333217600)> X Value: 4, 449
THREAD: <Thread(Thread-2, started daemon 140020317751040)> X Value: 5, 449
THREAD: <Thread(Thread-1, started daemon 140020326205184)> X Value: 4, 449
THREAD: <Thread(Thread-3, started daemon 140020309296896)> X Value: 5, 449
THREAD: <Thread(Thread-2, started daemon 140020317751040)> X Value: 4, 449
THREAD: <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140020333217600)> X Value: 4, 449
THREAD: <Thread(Thread-3, started daemon 140020309296896)> X Value: 4, 449
THREAD: <Thread(Thread-1, started daemon 140020326205184)> X Value: 4, 449
THREAD: <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140020333217600)> X Value: 3, 449
THREAD: <Thread(Thread-1, started daemon 140020326205184)> X Value: 3, 449
...

THREAD: <Thread(Thread-1, started daemon 140020326205184)> X Value: 5, 450
THREAD: <Thread(Thread-3, started daemon 140020309296896)> X Value: 5, 450
THREAD: <Thread(Thread-2, started daemon 140020317751040)> X Value: 5, 450
THREAD: <Thread(Thread-1, started daemon 140020326205184)> X Value: 4, 450
THREAD: <Thread(Thread-3, started daemon 140020309296896)> X Value: 5, 450
THREAD: <Thread(Thread-2, started daemon 140020317751040)> X Value: 4, 450
THREAD: <Thread(Thread-3, started daemon 140020309296896)> X Value: 4, 450
THREAD: <Thread(Thread-1, started daemon 140020326205184)> X Value: 4, 450
THREAD: <Thread(Thread-1, started daemon 140020326205184)> X Value: 3, 450
```

Is it because the print statement is called in the new process thread (prints "there" and also printed in the parent process?

I addition, what is the number after "started daemon" in thread information? If it is the memory address, why is it the same for child threads across the different processes? (The Main Thread address is different from all 2 processes spawned, which is expected).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your log looks like what I expect.  Remember that each thread is going to print a complete inventory of ALL threads in each loop.  Thus, I expect to see 28 log entries (4 threads x 7 iterations) for each process.

The number is a "thread identifier" local to the process.  If you're on LInux, the three processes are all exact copies of each other, so executing the same code will always end up with the same addresses.

Comment: Agreed. I do expect 28 log entries. However, I get 56 for some reason. My expectation is not to see a duplicate X Value for each unique Thread in a unique PID.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the thread identifier. That part is clear now.

Comment: You get 56 for each process?  That isn't clear from the output you showed.  Each thread id/process id/x combination appears to be unique.

Comment: As an example, if you look towards the top of the output, PID 449, Thread-1, you will see there are even 3 rows where X Value = 6. (row 2, row 6, row 7).. or row 1, row 5, row 6 if you index starting with 0.

Comment: Remember that the "x" you are printing is not the "x" for the thread shown in the log line.  It's the "x" for the thread that is taking inventory.  Thread 1 will print each thread with its value 6.  Thread 2 will print each thread with its value 6.  Thread 3 will print each thread with its value 6.